# Checking if polynomial can be iterated and only take prime values

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I have the polynomial $f(x) = x^2-x+1$ and I am wondering if there is a positive prime value $p$ such that $f(p),f^2(p),f^3(p)\dots$ are all prime.

I have ran some computer simulations and I feel like the answer should be "no" ( because looking at the map $x^2-x+1 \bmod p$ I get that the expected number of prime divisors of the first $M$ values should be larger than $M$). I feel that my analysis is not very good however.

Does anyone know an approach which could be more fruitful?

Note: $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$

Edit: I would be happy with any sort of reference regarding a polynomial staying inside the primes under iteration, if there isn't anything particularly useful which can be said about this sort of thing I understand that as well).

Comment: Something curious: for some primes, like $160117$ we get that all but $86$ residues $\bmod p$ stabilize at $1$ (which means they have to pass through $0$ first ), and there seem to be many primes like this.

Comment: FYI, your question is basically a special case of [Integer dynamics hitting infinitely many primes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/128780/129887), but you ask for $f^{n}(x)$  being prime for all $n$ where $x$ is a prime, instead of this being prime for just infinitely many $n$ which is asked about in the other question.

Comment: I know I've seen a similar question recently. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182382/polynomials-with-integer-coefficients-that-can-be-iterated-for-infinitely-many-t isn't the one I'm thinking of, but it is somewhat related.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: This is a completely different question. It asks for an example of a polynomial, here the polynomial is given.

Comment: I believe that no one can disprove that $2^{2^n}+1$ is prime for all sufficiently large $n$ (although no one believes this to be true). Since $2^{2^n}+1$ is $f^{(n)}(3)$ where $f(x) = (x-1)^2+1$, this means that we can't rule out that the iterates of a quadratic polynomial might always be prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but will point you toward work on the number theoretic properties of such sequences. Iteration of $x^2-x+1$ starting at $a=2$ is called the [Sylvester sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence). A theorem about primes that divide the terms in such sequences was proved by Rafe Jones ([The density of prime divisors in the arithmetic dynamics of quadratic polynomials. *J. Lond. Math. Soc.* (2) **78** (2008), no. 2, 523–544. MR2439638](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612415)) One of his results is that if $k\in\mathbb Z$ with $k\notin\{0,2\}$, then the set of primes dividing the integers in the orbit of any $a\in\mathbb Z$ under iteration of $x^2+kx-1$ has density $0$.

In a different direction, one can prove that the numbers in your sequence, for any starting prime $p$, grow quadratically exponentially, and in fact
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \log f^n(p) \quad\text{converges
to a positive real number.} $$ Thus your sequence is growing very rapidly, which means that we have very few tools at our disposal to prove statements of the sort you ask.

Comment: But there are tools to **disprove** the statement. It is highly unlikely there exists such a prime $p$ and it is quite possible there exists an elementary proof of this statement.

Comment: @MarkSapir That's a good point. For example, it's easy to prove a polynomial cannot take on only prime values, and iteration of "easy" polynomials such as $f(x)=x^d$ are also trivial. However, for $x^2-x+1$, I don't see an easy congruence-type argument, so I'm not sure I'd be so confident as to say "quite possible", but I'd be willing to go with "not inconceivable". :) From a probabilistic perspective, the probability that $f^n(p)$ is prime should be $O(1/2^n)$, so most likely there are only finitely many primes in the sequence.

Comment: the difficulty is that the members of the sequence are mutually coprime: each member is congruent to 1 modulo all previous, that does not allow to look for prime divisors from the same sequence

Comment: @FedorPetrov Very true, so the elementary congruence-divisibility argument for values of polynomials won't work, i.e., there is no identity like $$f\bigl(m+nf(m)\bigr)\equiv0\pmod{f(m)}\quad\text{for all fixed $m$ and all $n$.} $$ OTOH, there are other ways to prove compositeness, e.g., if $$2^N\not\equiv2\pmod{N},$$ then $N$ is composite. And there are similar criteria using quadratic residues. Not that I have any idea how one might use this to prove compositeness for a number in the sequence $f^n(p)$, but I'd want to think about it a lot more before entirely ruling out such an approach.